# nodejs: Database doesnot exist

Tags: node.js

I am writing a code to fetch data from the database and display it on the server. However when I run the command `localhost:3000` in the browser, the page is not displayed and the error printed on the console is that `database "recipies" does not exist`. However, I have an existing postgreSQL database named 'recipies' and when I run command from postgreSQL console, data is inserted and can be viewed from the table.

The problem is that i have an existing database named "recipies", however, the error shows that the database "recipies" doesnot exist.

CODE:

```
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
cons = require('consolidate'),
dust = require('dustjs-helpers'),
pg = require('pg'),
app = express();


const config = {
    user: 'postgres',
    database: 'recipies',
    host: '40.83.121.72',
    password: 'HelloWorld',
    port: 5432
};

const connectionString = 'postgres://postgres:HelloWorld@localhost:3000/'


app.engine('dust',cons.dust);

app.set('view engine','dust');
app.set('views',__dirname+'/views');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

const pool = new pg.Pool(config);

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
   pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
       if (err) {
           console.log("Can not connect to the DB" + err);
       }
       client.query('SELECT * FROM recipies', function (err, result) {

            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            //res.status(200).send(result.rows);
            res.render('index',{recipies:result.rows});
            done();
       });
   });
});

app.listen(3000, function(){

console.log('Server started on port 3000');

});
```

ERROR:

```
 client.query('SELECT * FROM recipies', function (err, result) {
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
    at PendingItem.callback (F:\recipiebook2\app.js:72:15)
    at client.connect (F:\recipiebook2\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:248:23)
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (F:\recipiebook2\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:163:14)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\recipiebook2\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:125:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

Comment: Why are you connecting to @localhost:3000 in your connectstring?

Comment: Furthermore, if your connect function gives an error, you should not try to execute queries on the client. Ie, return after the first errormessage.

Answer (score 0):

Yours connect string is incorrect. It should be like below.

```
const connectionString = 'postgres://db_username:db_password@localhost/db_name'
```

Comment: const connectionString = 'postgres://postgres:HelloWorld@localhost/recipies' . I have tried changing the code with the above line. But even this is not helping.

Comment: `HelloWorld` is your password?

Comment: Yes that's my password.

Comment: @AnwesaRoy  Is your postgres server running on localhost? Or is it running on host `40.83.121.72` which is mentioned in the `config` variable.

Comment: @derpirscher my server is running on localhost:3000. Actually I put the table name (recipies) instead of the database name in the string : const connectionString = 'postgres://db_username:db_password@localhost/db_name' which is why I was facing the problem.